# Gallery doesn't refresh using MediaScan

Tags: java, android

I have the following Java code which downloads an image from an URL.
I can see the image downloaded in the folder, but the image does not appear in gallery. Only if I restart phone, Samsung S7 with android 7, I can see images in gallery. What can I do to have the images in gallery in real time after I downloaded them?

```
public class DetailsImgActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "DetailsImgActivity";
    private ImageView imageViewPoze;
    private Button buttonDownload;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_img);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

        }

        // image url stored in imageID
        final String imageId = getIntent().getStringExtra("ImageId");


        imageViewPoze = findViewById(R.id.imageViewPozeC);
        Picasso.get().load(imageId).into(imageViewPoze);

        buttonDownload = findViewById(R.id.btn_Download_Img);
        buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                downloadFile(imageId);
            }
        });
    }

    private void downloadFile(String url) {
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://firebasestorage.blabla.com/");
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        FileDownloadClient fileDownloadClient = retrofit.create(FileDownloadClient.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = fileDownloadClient.downloadFile(url);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, final Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                //  if (response.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "server contacted and has file");
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                        boolean writtenToDisk = writeResponseBodyToDisk(response.body());

                        return null;
                    }
                }.execute();

                //after the image has been downloaded -refresh gallery 
                **Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File downloaded with success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                {
                    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                    File f = new File("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES));
                    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                    sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
                }
                else
                {
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                }**

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error");
            }
        });
    }



    private boolean writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body) {
        try {

            String folder_main =  Constants.dirName;

            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), folder_main);
            if (!f.exists()) {
                f.mkdirs();
            }


            // todo change the file location/name according to your needs
            File futureStudioIconFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM+"/"+ Constants.dirName)
                    + File.separator + UUID.randomUUID()+".jpg");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;

            try {
                byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];

                long fileSize = body.contentLength();
                long fileSizeDownloaded = 0;

                inputStream = body.byteStream();
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(futureStudioIconFile);

                while (true) {
                    int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);

                    if (read == -1) {
                        break;
                    }

                    outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);

                    fileSizeDownloaded += read;

                    Log.d(TAG, "file download: " + fileSizeDownloaded + " of " + fileSize);
                }

                outputStream.flush();

                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }

                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I used the follwing code, but If I don't reboot phone, I can't see the picture in gallery.

```
**Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File downloaded with success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                {
                    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                    File f = new File("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES));
                    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                    sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
                }
                else
                {
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                }**
```

Comment: You should be crashing with a `FileUriExposedException` on Android 7.0+. Use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method instead of `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` or `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED`.

Comment: Can you provide some example code?

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.11/MediaProjection/andcorder/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/andcorder/RecordingSession.java#L83-L84

Comment: I tried with MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ctxt,
      new String[]{path}, null, this); but no luck

Comment: Then the problem may be in the gallery app, not your code.